# Mathcad error: " his array index invalid for this array"

Tags: mathcad

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNlBp.png)

How solution this problem

Answer (score 0):

Range matrix index must change from 0 to rows count-1 or from 0 to cols count-1 see example[image] I don't understand about variable f?